# Coldfusion 8 and HTTP PUT - is there a way to PUT an object?

Tags: java, http, coldfusion, serialization, ehcache

We are using EHCache with CF 8 to cache stuff on a central server using a RESTful interface over HTTP. I am trying to cache a cfquery **object** to the cache server.

I can get this to work if I call EHCache direct (i.e. store it in a local cache) but if I try to cache on a remote server over HTTP I am running into problems.

The code I am using is as follows:

```
<cfhttp url="http://localhost:8080/myCache/myKey"
  method="put" 
  result="r" 
  timeout="2" 
  throwonerror="true" >
    <cfhttpparam type="body" value="#ARGUMENTS.item#" />
</cfhttp>
```

CF doesn't like this reference to `#ARGUMENTS.item#` and it complains `Complex object types cannot be converted to simple values.`

Can anyone give me an example of how to put an object over http using CF? If this is not possible with CF then a Java example would be the next best thing.

Many thanks in advance!

PS: I do not want to use serialization to text/JSON etc. as this approach has issues with data integrity and most importantly it's not fast enough.

Comment: Can you switch to CF9? It has ehcache hooks built in.

Comment: The value passed in cfhttpparam/value MUST be a string - either text or binary. You are going to have to serialize arguments.item in some way.

Comment: @kevink - CF9 only allows caching to local system, not to a central cache server AFAIK. We are using a clustered environment.

Comment: @CF Jedi Master - What's the fastest way to serialize? The JSON approach via CF is pretty expensive.

Comment: Maybe try using a native Java JSON serializer - not one built in CF itself. Yes, I know that CF ultimately gets compiled to JVM bytecode, but a parser written in native Java might perform better than a CF rolled one. Just a thought. Or maybe use Protocol Buffers for binary serialization.

Comment: An extreme option would be to look at Railo, I believe the next version will have extensive ehcache support too and they may have cluster support, not positive though. Before doing that I would make sure serializing is really where your bottleneck is though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out I can use the exact code above if I do the following to the `ARGUMENTS.item` variable before I pass it to the function:

```
<cfquery name="qData" datasource="#VARIABLES.dsn#">
select * from myData
</cfquery>

<!--- Setup and init Java objects --->
<cfset byteArrayOutputStream = createObject("java","java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream") />
<cfset objectOutputStream = createObject("java","java.io.ObjectOutputStream") />
<cfset byteArrayOutputStream.init() />
<cfset objectOutputStream.init(byteArrayOutputStream) />

<!--- Serialize the cfquery object --->
<cfset objectOutputStream.writeObject(qData) />
<cfset serializedQuery = toBase64(byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray()) />
<cfset objectOutputStream.close() />    

<!--- Stick in the cache --->
<cfset myCache.put(myCacheName, key, serializedQuery) />
```

Bingo! After that `serializedQuery` is there to be used and it can be PUT across the wire via HTTP. When you get it back from EHCache, the you need to do the following:

```
<!--- Get result value from cache --->
<cfset cacheData = myCache.get(myCacheName, key) />

<!--- Java objects setup --->
<cfset byteArrayInputStream  = createObject("java","java.io.ByteArrayInputStream") />
<cfset objectInputStream = createObject("java","java.io.ObjectInputStream") />

<!--- deserialize --->
<cfset ba = toBinary(cacheData) />
<cfset byteArrayInputStream.init(ba) />
<cfset objectInputStream.init(byteArrayInputStream) />
<cfset deserializedQuery = objectInputStream.readObject() />
<cfset objectInputStream.close() />

<!--- Dump query --->
<cfdump var="#deserializedQuery#" />
```

This type of serialization is very, very quick too. I can understand others using JSON representations but I'm not sure they are as fast.

Anyway, this seems to work great for me. Thank you all for your input. I hope others find this useful.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you will have to serialize the arguments structure because there is no way to pass binary objects via HTTP without some form of serialization. As has already been mentioned, you can use JSON to serialize the object. An alternative to JSON that would also work is the cfwddx tag which can convert the object into XML. But JSON is probably better because it's not as verbose as the XML generated by cfwddx.